# Finding the surface area of a spoon using integration?

Tags: integration, area

I do not know exactly what shape is a spoon. I feel like it is an elliptical paraboloid but really I don't know. I really need to do this for my math project. Any help would be very appreciated!

**Image of a sample shape**
[image: image of a sample shape]

Comment: You could regard the shape of a spoon as an elliptic paraboloid. Maybe use Green's theorem(let $F(x,y)=(-y,x)$) to compute the surface area.

Comment: Seems like you'd run into elliptic integrals here, no?

Comment: The expression is not going to be nice at all.